# Is there anyway to contact administrators asking for review?

Tags: support, down-votes

Recently I've posted a question with a detailed explanation of the problem, I've provided JavaScript and HTML code, plus two jsFiddles.

Still, I got two downvoters that did not explain why. I asked both of downvoters to tell me what I was doing wrong so I could fix it and got nothing for response.

I think I am being victim of users that downvote others' questions and answers to see themselves with better reputation. How can we ask moderarors for help with this kind of a problem?

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463892/jquery-validate-is-there-anyway-to-use-sub-groups) of the question.

Comment: There's nothing moderators can do about it...

Comment: Seriously? So, users with more points actually can prejudice others and we can't do nothing about it?

Comment: People are free to vote as they please. As long as they're not targeting a specific user, no, there's nothing we can do. If a user wants to go downvote 40 random questions every day for no reason - well that would be a sucky thing for them to do, but they haven't broken any rules.

Comment: There's no gain (or loss) from voting for a question either way, and voting is anonymous by design and there is no requirement to explain (which would make it non-anonymous). Users vote on the quality of questions. If you got two downvotes and no other responses, the question may not have been as clear as you think. (I've read your post, and I have no idea what you're asking for help solving, BTW. I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Having read the question, I can't tell what you're asking for help with. A *tl;dr* would be nice.

Comment: @KenWhite, what didn't sound clear to you? I'm brazilian and maybe I can improve my writing to make it clearer to you.

Comment: @michaelb958 what's `tl;dr`?

Comment: As I can observe, maybe this is cultural, the way English speakers handle things, and the way Portuguese speakers do. I got two downvotes here and nobody bothered to explain why.

Comment: @Philippe *tl;dr* is a relatively common Internet shorthand for *too long, didn't read*. Because of that, it's also used as a header for summaries of a long post.

Comment: @michaelb958 so I didn't understand what you meant by "A tl;dr would be nice."

Answer (score 16):

Despite the fact that troubleshooting questions are asked all the time on Stack Overflow, the truth is that these questions are not all that interesting to the experts on the site, and they're even less interesting when it is not evident what the solution to a highly-specific troubleshooting problem is.

This is especially true when the question gives all appearances of being thoroughly researched and thought-out, but it becomes apparent that lengthy troubleshooting and analysis needs to be performed.  It's a question that, at the end of the day, amounts to "this doesn't work, can you tell me why?" Or, worse, "Can you troubleshoot this for me and tell me why it's broken, or provide me code that does work?"

Most of the experts here would have to perform the work that you should have undertaken yourself, which is to trace through the code, examine its behavior, and through the deductive process and a process of self-education, come up with a fix.  That's part of your job as a programmer.  Our job is to help you *facilitate* that work, not perform the work for you.

In other words, we are here to teach you how to fish, not to fish.

Comment: +1 nice, `we are here to teach you how to fish, not to fish.`

Comment: how to fish, not to fish [for you], @PraveenJeganathan

Comment: I didn't ask for someone to do it for me, I even provided my logics and use cases. What I really wanna do is if it's possible to achieve the behaviour I want or if it's not possible at all, at least with the plugin I'm using, that's I asked "is there anyway to use subgroups?" and not "can you teach me how to use subgroups?". I don't want nobody to solve the problem for me, I want to tell me is it's possible or not.

Comment: "If it's possible or not" is what I meant.

Comment: For the moderation team, I have another example: I've asked this [question](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3647/quando-usar-condicao-ternaria/) in SO in Portuguese and look how many good answers we had, in fact, the debate is still on. So, is this really a bad question? But look how the SO moderation team described the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489308/when-to-use-ternary-conditions) in English. PS: I suggest you to use Google Translator to read the question and the answers.